# Showing $K = I \otimes_R K$, where $K$ is the field of fractions of $R$.

Tags: commutative-algebra, tensor-products

A question in a previous Commutative Algebra Exam reads:

> **Problem.** Let $R$ denote an integral domain, $K$ its field of fractions.
>
> Let $I$ denote a non-zero ideal of $R$.
>
> Show that $K=I \otimes_R K.$

The only thing I've been able to think of is letting $i$ denote a non-zero element of $I$, and defining $$\eta : K \rightarrow I \otimes_R K,\;\;k \mapsto i \otimes k$$

Its clear that $\eta$ is linear, but it seems not to preserve multiplication. All I can get is:

$$\eta(xy) = i^{-1}\eta(x)\eta(y)$$

which isn't very good.

Ideas, anyone?

Comment: In fact, it suddenly occurs to me that I'm not really sure what it means to tensor an $R$-algebra (like $K$) with an $R$-module (like $I$). Am I missing something here?

Comment: There is a theorem in Atiyah-MacDonald saying that $I \otimes_R K = S^{-1}I$ (where $S$ are then nonzero  elementsin $R$). Hence $1 \in S^{-1}I$, so $S^{-I}I = R \otimes K = K$.

Comment: Maybe you can try to define $\eta (k)= i\otimes i^{-1} k$ for some nonzero $i$ in $I$.

Comment: Here is a basic principle dealing with tensor products. If at all possible, try to define a map from a tensor product to another module and not the other way around. This, by using universal property, is just defining a bilinear map, which often is easier. In your case, you have a map $I\times K\to K$, defined as $(i,k)\mapsto ik$. Thus,you get a module homomorphism $I\otimes K\to K$. Try to check that this is an isomorphism.

Comment: @Mohan, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$K$ is a flat $R$-module, hence the exact sequence $$0 \to I \to R \to R/I \to 0$$ gives rise to an exact sequence $$0 \to I \otimes K \to R \otimes K \to R/I \otimes K \to 0.$$ The middle term is $K$. The right term is $K/IK=0$, hence the left term is isomorphic to the middle term.

---

The fact that tensoring with $K$ is the same as localizing at $\mathfrak p=0$ gives rise to a natural generalization of the statement: Given an ideal $I \subset R$ and a prime $\mathfrak p \subset R$, one can ask whether the localized inclusion $I_\mathfrak p \subset R_\mathfrak p$ is surjective, i.e. whether $I_\mathfrak p = R_\mathfrak p$. This is a very easy exercise and the answer is that $I_\mathfrak p = R_\mathfrak p$ if and only if $I$ is not contained in $\mathfrak p$ (since this means that we find an element in $I$, which is a unit in $R_\mathfrak p$).

In our case, we had $\mathfrak p=0$, i.e. $I \otimes K = K$ holds if and only if $I$ is not contained in $0$, i.e. iff $I$ is non-zero.

Comment: There's something I'm a little confused about here: is it a general principle that $R/I \otimes S = S/IS$ for all $R$-algebras $S$? If not, what's going on there?

Comment: Yes, that is always true (for any R-module, in particular for R-algebras).

Comment: Small comment: tensor product is only right exact in general, something should be said about why it is injective on the left (which is true).

Comment: In the first line of my answer, I state '$K$ is flat' :)

Comment: Of course the reason for $K$ being flat comes from the fact that localization is exact and tensoring with $K$ is the same as localizing at the zero-ideal. Since the OP hasn't further asked about this, I assumed he is aware of this.